# existing technology (similar to html) to develop UI for Desktop application in java

Tags: java, javascript, html, css, desktop-application

I want to develop a Desktop Application using Java.
I want to know which are the best technologies to develop User Interface.
It would be ideal to find a technology that supports html, css and javascript (as in web development) but avoid the high cost of a server  and instead will use events like swing.
I would also like to be portable as java
Is there something similar?

**EDIT something like this would be ideal [TideSDK](http://www.tidesdk.org/)**

Comment: You're looking for swing and java fx

Answer (score 2):

The current (primary) UI tool kits (excluding 3D tool kits and dedicated 2D tool kits) that are available are...

- [Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/)
- [JavaFX (2)](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/)
- [AWT](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-07-1996/jw-07-awt.html)
- [SWT](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/)

Swing has been around for over 13 years, has an established base of libraries and 3rd party support, has a wide and experienced community of users.  It does/has however been over shadowed by JavaFX recently.

JavaFX is a relatively new player on the field and was touted (amongst other things) as a Flash competitor.  Version 2 adds the ability to construct UI code directly without needing to rely on it's scripting element (as much)

AWT is the original UI toolkit and was "replaced" by Swing, although Swing still utilizes it to perform it's work

SWT has been around for a while (I'm unfamiliar with it's history and have never used it).

> SWT is an open source widget toolkit for Java designed to provide
>   efficient, portable access to the user-interface facilities of the
>   operating systems on which it is implemented.

The closes match to your requirements would be JavaFX, but wouldn't entirely meet them

Comment: something like this would be ideal http://www.tidesdk.org/